# send an array from php to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to send an array that is being created on a php file to a javascript file.
The codes that I have made are the below but I cannot make it work.

sample.php

```
<form action="new-game.php" method="post">
<?php $playerNames = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$_POST["playerNo"]; $i++) {
        echo "<form name=\"input\" action=\"#\" method=\"POST\">Όνομα: <input type=\"text\" name=\"playerName\" value=\"\"><br/>";
        $playerNames[$i] = $_REQUEST['playerName'];
    }
?>

    </br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Αποστολή" onclick='showNames(<?php echo json_encode($playerNames); ?>);' />
</form>
```

And I don't know how I should use the $playerNames array on script.js file.

Comment: First, I would advice to close the php tag before write the html, better to read the code.

Comment: I dono what you want to do but var data2 = <?php echo json_encode($playerNames );?>; should do it for you

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors? Where is your JavaScript code to handle the player data?

Comment: I don't know how to check for console errors. The javascript code file is on the same site as the php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your javascript file ? And is the function showNames() present ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

Look at my example to send datas from PHP to Javascript.
The trick is to close the PHP tag, and to open a Javascript one.

```
<?php
    $my_array; //replace by your own array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($my_array) -1; $i++) {
    ?>
        <script>
            myFunction(<?php echo $my_array[$i]; ?> );
        </script>
    <?php   
} 
?>
```

**EDIT :**

It seems to me that this line is wrong.

```
<input type="submit" value="Αποστολή" onclick='showNames(<?php echo json_encode($playerNames); ?>);' />
```

Try using this following one instead :

```
<input type="submit" value="Αποστολή" onclick='showNames(<?php echo json_encode($playerNames); ?>)' />
```

Comment: I have included the javascript file to the head. I don't understand how to make the function of showNames() to the javascript file. Any help on this?

Comment: Verify your input : 
<input type="submit" value="Αποστολή" onclick='showNames(<?php echo json_encode($playerNames); ?>);' />

There's a character that does not belong here. Try removing the last ';' and it should work.

Comment: and on js file I use the $playerNames directly as an array. I have only declared it on the js file...